# Mobile phone explosion

Tags: power-electronics, telephone

There have been several cases of mobile device **explosion** while charging and using to make call.
 There is also cases of **power bank exploding**  while using it to charge phone [but not plug to ac source].

Why is this happening, is there extra energy introduced in the system?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the main reason for these explosions are that their Lithium-Ion based batteries overheat. These problems are caused by manufacturing defects or sometimes bad design (in the Boeing 787, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner_battery_problems))

The energy does not need to be introduced to the system as it is already there inside the battery. What can happen is that the battery shorts internally discharging itself through that short. This generates a lot of heat which can lead to fire and/or an explosion.

There's an interesting article on this subject [here at Batteryuniversity.com](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_concerns_with_li_ion)

Comment: It doesn't help that many Lithium Ion battery formulations are flammable.  Not only do they overheat due to the internal short circuit, but they then catch fire.

Comment: In one survial show Bear Grils used a phone battery to start a fire by stabbing it with his knife ... It was nice to see his expression as it caught fire very fast... Failure to research I believe it is called....